# webdriver-io closeWindow is not triggering beforeUnload event

Tags: vue.js, webdriver-io

This is a Vue 3 project and I've created a minimal reproduction scenario that seems to show this. In the beforeUnload event handler I write to a (shared) pinia store to track activity.  Manual testing shows the entries from beforeUnload appearing when I refresh or close the browser tab.  Doing a browser.refresh does trigger beforeUnload and writes the log entries.  Doing a browser.closeWindow does not produce any log entries.

I have a "debug" route that displays the log.  The log from a manual refresh/close test:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WOfN.png)

The same view from the webdriver-io test:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUL5t.png)

The beforeUnload code is in this component:

```
<template>
<h1>{{ tab_id }}</h1>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { onBeforeMount, Ref, ref } from "vue";
import { useAppLog } from "../stores/appLog"
const appLog = useAppLog()
const tab_id: Ref<string> = ref("")
onBeforeMount(() => {
    tab_id.value = appLog.new_tab()
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (e) => {
      appLog.close_tab(tab_id.value)
    })
})
</script>
```

This is the store:

```
export const useAppLog = defineStore('appLog', {
    state: () => ({
        action_log: [""]
    }),
    actions: {
        new_tab(): string {
            const tab_id:string = uuidv4()
            this.action_log.unshift(`${tab_id} - opened tab - new or refresh`)
            return tab_id
        },
        close_tab(tab_id: string): void {
            this.action_log.unshift(`${tab_id} - closed tab - close or refresh`)
        },
        clear_log(): void {
            this.action_log = []
        }
    },
    persist: true
})
```

I'm using "pinia-plugin-persistedstate": "^3.2.0", and "pinia-shared-state": "^0.4.5" to maintain the store between tabs and across refreshes.

The debug page is this component:

```
<template>
  <h1 id="debug-header">Debug View</h1>
  <h3>Mode: {{ mode }}</h3>

  <div>
    <div>Log</div>
    <button @click="clear_log">Clear Log</button>
    <div>
      <div
          v-for="log in action_log"
      >
        {{ log }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import {onMounted, Ref, ref} from "vue"
import { useAppLog } from "../stores/appLog"
import {storeToRefs} from "pinia"
const appLog = useAppLog()

const { action_log } = storeToRefs(appLog)

const mode: Ref<string> = ref(import.meta.env.MODE)

const clear_log = () => {
  appLog.clear_log()
}
</script>
```

Here is the test script:

```
describe('refresh test', () => {
    it('should open debug page', async () => {
        await browser.url(`http://localhost:5173/debug`)

        await expect($('#debug-header')).toBeExisting()
        await expect($('#debug-header')).toHaveTextContaining(
            'Debug View')
    })

    it('should open 2 normal windows and refresh/close them', async () => {
        const debug_handle = await browser.getWindowHandle()
        await browser.newWindow("http://localhost:5173/")
        const window1_handle = await browser.getWindowHandle()
        await browser.newWindow("http://localhost:5173")
        const window2_handle = await browser.getWindowHandle()

        await browser.switchToWindow(debug_handle)
        await browser.pause(5000)

        // refresh window2
        await browser.switchToWindow(window2_handle)
        await browser.refresh()
        await browser.switchToWindow(debug_handle)
        await browser.pause(5000)

        // refresh window1
        await browser.switchToWindow(window1_handle)
        await browser.refresh()
        await browser.switchToWindow(debug_handle)
        await browser.pause(5000)

        // close window2
        await browser.switchToWindow(window2_handle)
        await browser.closeWindow()
        await browser.switchToWindow(debug_handle)
        await browser.pause(5000)

        // close window1
        await browser.switchToWindow(window1_handle)
        await browser.closeWindow()
        await browser.switchToWindow(debug_handle)
        await browser.pause(30000)
    })
})
```

The images showing state seem to clearly show that when manually refreshing and closing the tabs beforeUnload is invoked in both cases, but that doesn't seem to be the case with browser.closeWindow.  I've searched StackOverflow and beyond, but haven't found anything related to this issue.